# How to go from one page to another depending on the data they receive when opening the app

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to make an application that has three types of users: Students, Teachers and Parents, what I do is save the id of the user token using shared_preferences at login, and I want it to search the database when entering the app and depending on what type of user it is, go to its corresponding page

So far i'm trying this

```
import 'package:app_plantel/padres_page.dart';
import 'package:app_plantel/profesores_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    isLogged(context);
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.beach_access,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<String> _returnValue() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final token = await prefs.getString("token");
  return token;
}

Future isLogged(context) async {

  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Padres')
    .doc(_returnValue().toString())
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) async {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> PadresPage()));
      } else {
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Alumnos')
        .doc(_returnValue().toString())
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) async {
          if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>  AlumnosPage()));
          } else {
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Profesores')
            .doc(_returnValue().toString())
            .get()
            .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) async {
              if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> ProfesoresPage()));
              } else {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> LoginPage()));
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
}
```

But it throws me a lot of mistakes:

```
E/flutter (13461): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
E/flutter (13461): The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.
E/flutter (13461): #0      Navigator.of.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2553:9)
E/flutter (13461): #1      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2560:6)
E/flutter (13461): #2      isLogged.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:app_plantel/main.dart:53:27)
E/flutter (13461): #3      isLogged.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:app_plantel/main.dart:49:19)
E/flutter (13461): #4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)
E/flutter (13461): #5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter (13461): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13461): #6      isLogged.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:app_plantel/main.dart:45:13)
E/flutter (13461): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13461): #7      isLogged.<anonymous closure> (package:app_plantel/main.dart:37:9)
E/flutter (13461): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13461): #8      isLogged (package:app_plantel/main.dart:29:3)
E/flutter (13461): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13461):
```

I would like to know how to solve it or some other method that they propose to be able to do it

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown because you don't have a `MaterialApp` or a `CupertinoApp` widget above your `Scaffold`, and it is needed for navigation. Something like this:

```
return const MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Icon(
        Icons.beach_access,
      ),
    ),
  )
);
```

Besides, your `isLogged` function is `async`, but you can't await it in the `build` method. Consider using a `FutureBuilder` to wait for the database responses before you start building the main widget.

Answer (score 0):

The context you passed in isLogged method is not wrapped with navigator.
You can set a global variable `final _navKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();`
then wrap you UI with Material app and set material app navigator key

```
const MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Icon(
        Icons.beach_access,
      ),
    ),
  ),
navigatorKey: _navKey
);
```

Finally use the key to retrieve navigator context and use when calling your navigator `_navKey.currentState?.context`